# Angular Material From Reset from Typescript side

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material2, reset

ok so you can do this :

```
<form #form="ngForm">
     ...
    <button (click)="form.reset()"> CLEAR ALL FIELDS </button>
</form>
```

but what if I want to achieve this form the code side?

I tried :

```
export class Admin {
  newUser: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){
    this.newUser = this.fb.group({
      login: '',
      name: '',
      password: '',
      confirm: '',
      profile: ''
    });
  }

reset(){
  this.newUser.reset();
}
```

but I get (this is after a validate and subsequent send by api of the form) : 
[image: the input fields are indeed cleared but turn red, as-in : the inputs are not untouched and required]

The the lines show up red as-in: the inputs are not untouched and since they are required these two qualities together set off material's "light the inputs red for error".

the point being, in my scenario the user isn't allowed to reset the form but a successful api return should trigger that.

Comment: Please explain your image. Some people can't see it because of proxies.

Comment: okay. I did it.

Comment: Thank you. I don't see it not working in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vcmcei?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html), so please make a [mcve] out of it (something that shows your issue)

Comment: did I mention mat-forms? oh yeah I did. here's my html : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tunmxq?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: The validation logic is about Angular, not about Material. And your blitz doesn't work, make it work. And last thing, quit the sassy behavior, you're in no position to allow yourself to be sassy.